# Can't find by whatever on DynamoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I've created my model, set up the table properly etc, data gets saved however when I try to search for things I get errors

```
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/record/scope.rb:169:in `send': undefined method `title' for Prop:Class (NoMethodError)
```

When trying to find with conditions:

```
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/record/scope.rb:169:in `send': undefined method `conditions' for Prop:Class (NoMethodError)
```

When trying Prop.where("title = 'blah')

```
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.8.0/lib/aws/record/scope.rb:169:in `send': undefined method `where' for Prop:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Basically my table is called Prop and the attributes are id, title, date_time, and so on. Anything other than find(id) or find_by_id(id) fails with that error.

Is there something else I was supposed to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDb keys are either Hash, or Hash-Range combo.

DynamoDb only lets you query on the keys (unless you defined the new LSI - [local secondary indexes](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/04/18/amazon-dynamodb-announces-local-secondary-indexes/)).

Even with LSI, you still can't make a complex query on tables that don't have a range key attribute.

If your Prop object has only a hash key attribute - id.
You will have to search all the table (operation called [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)) and in your app filter the ones you want

Comment: Thank you for that. Just read through and saw it allows up to 5 local indexes, I have 6 ideally 7 columns which I should index actually. Any ideas?

Comment: I would advise you to start a new question and asks for help modeling the specific data you need. Without it I can just guess that DynamoDB LSI isn't the solution.